# Change SocialTag Url?

Tags: powershell, social-tag

I want to change the url of my solution from mycompany.**no** to mycompany.**com**.
How can I preserve the Social Tags. SocialTag Url property is readonly it appears. :( Does there exist a powershell or something for social tags similar to Move-SPSocialComments http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh393959.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if you configure a valid alternate access mapping you can resolve your problem.

In this page you can find how to configure it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208(office.12).aspx

Comment: While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer] for general guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Or you create a script that **Create** the tag with the same properties except the url, afterwards you **Delete** the old tag.

More information about the SocialTagManager: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.socialdata.socialtagmanager_members.aspx.

Comment: That would work, but I think the AAM path is a more suited approach in my case since it would require less work. Also with AAM I dont need to impersonate the individual users to get the names on the tags right.